# How to Sort in .NET Same as a SQL Server Collation?

Tags: sql-server, sorting, linq-to-xml, collation

I've been doing some TDD against some existing stored procedures. They return XML, so I've been  using LINQ to XML.

At the moment, I'm working on a test that will prove that the data have been sorted properly. The test navigates through the XML, and creates an IEnumerable of an anonymous type containing the three columns that should be sorted. From that, it creates a second IEnumerable by sorting the first:

```
var sortedColumns = from g in columns
                    orderby g.ColumnA ascending,
                            g.ColumnB ascending,
                            g.ColumnC ascending
                    select g;
```

Finally, it asserts that the sorted colums are the same as the unsorted ones using SequenceEquals.

The problem comes when the database collation differs from the current collation. In particular, .NET is placing "W-" before "Wa" in ColumnB.

Is there a way to sort in the same order as an arbitrary SQL Server collation? If not, then how would I sort in the same order as SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS?

Comment: Related questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562042/achieving-consistent-sorting-between-c-sharp-and-sql-using-collationinfo-compare, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9384642/what-net-stringcomparer-is-equivalent-sqls-latin1-general-ci-as, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5581268/custom-collation-ordering

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If is a Windows collation, then it boils down to setting the appropriate locale and sort order, as in [Sort Order Identifiers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd374060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), which in .Net world goes by the currently set UI culture.

If is a SQL collation, then is a bit more complicated. If you use VARCHAR you're out of lock. For NVARCHAR, there is some hope. See [Comparing SQL collations to Windows collations](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/322112):

> A SQL collation's rules for sorting
>   non-Unicode data are incompatible with
>   any sort routine that is provided by
>   the Microsoft Windows operating
>   system; however, the sorting of
>   Unicode data is compatible with a
>   particular version of the Windows
>   sorting rules. Because the comparison
>   rules for non-Unicode and Unicode data
>   are different, when you use a SQL
>   collation you might see different
>   results for comparisons of the same
>   characters, depending on the
>   underlying data type. For example, if
>   you are using the SQL collation
>   "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS", the
>   non-Unicode string 'a-c' is less than
>   the string 'ab' because the hyphen
>   ("-") is sorted as a separate
>   character that comes before "b".
>   However, if you convert these strings
>   to Unicode and you perform the same
>   comparison, the Unicode string N'a-c'
>   is considered to be greater than N'ab'
>   because the Unicode sorting rules use
>   a "word sort" that ignores the hyphen.

For your purposes (TDD) I would recommend simply staying away from suspicious characters, like hyphen `-`, or having two `s` one after another (German ss issues), or capital `I` (Turkish colliton issues), `sh` (Spanish collation issues) etc etc... Stick to a small subset of characters that sort properly, like `a,A,b,B`. I'm serious.

Comment: Unfortunately, we don't get to use clean data - I have to use what's there.

Comment: How about using  SQLite or SQL CE for the test store? Them have collations.

Comment: Or, "radical concept", use a "unit test database" for the unit tests, not the same database I use to test the application with in the integration environment. Hmmm.

Comment: sorry it's taken so long to accept your answer. You set me on the right track. All of my database-related unit tests since January have inserted test data within a transaction (possibly truncating tables first), and then rolled back at the end of the test. I'm working towards "datadude" database unit tests, which start by deploying a clean copy of the database, then populating it via data generation plans.

Comment: So how can I use a .Net Comparer to mimic the rules of the Windows "SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS" collation?  I'm not finding any good info on this topic (besides this answer).  I don't want to have to load the sqlparser library to use it's prebuilt comparers if it's possible to avoid it and still get 100% accurate results (relative to sql server's implementation).

Answer (score 1):

Write a custom `IComparer` implementation that actually calls out to SQL server to compare each of the two values it's asked to compare.

It would be very slow, a little silly, but it would do exactly what you're asking.

Or if you only care about replicating one particular collation sequence exactly and not any random collation, then write a one-time-use routine to call out to SQL Server and build you a collection of all characters in the order SQL server will put them and use that to build a custom `IComparer` implementation which will then match SQL server's sequence without calling out to SQL server at run time.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I wish I could upvote it twice. I'd mark it as the accepted answer, except that Remus Rusanu's answer actually set me on the correct path - what I think is the right way to handle all of these issues - create your own data, either in a clean database, or by doing it in a transaction and rolling back at the end of the test.

Answer (score 0):

LINQ-to-SQL doesn't support direct use of collations. If you want to achieve a special sorting, you will have to get the data locally, transform it to a list (or whatever) and sort it yourself.

For further reference see the following two links:

- [LINQ sorting is not working at all](http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/299305/linq-sorting-is-not-working-at-all)
- [NET Framework Function Support and Notes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb425822.aspx#linqtosql_topic36)

Comment: Sorry, I guess I wasn't clear. I'm not using LINQ to SQL - I'm using LINQ to XML on some XML that came from SQL Server.

Comment: Oh, nevermind then. I'll just let this response here, maybe it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

I've lifted this from [use-own-icomparert-with-linq-orderby](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985657).

```
        MyComparer comparer = new MyComparer();
        items = items.OrderByDescending(
                  x => property.GetValue(x), comparer).ToList();
        break;
```

You could create a custom comparer for your needs.  (You might need a concrete type instead of an anonymous type for your results - I haven't actually tested this).

Comment: Thanks, but which comparer? Is there a generic way to create a comparer that matches any SQL Server collation, or can you show me code to compare like SQL_Latin1_General_CP_CI_AI?

Comment: I don't believe there's an out of the box IComparer for a SQL Server collation.  You'd need to create a class that implements IComparer, and make the appropriate comparisons yourself.

Comment: (cont..) I'm not saying it's going to be pretty :)  Obviously, if you specifically want SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AI, you could perform a ToLower() (CI).  I guess a Search/Replace for the accents (AI)?  That's a bit further than I've researched...