# What .NET StringComparer is equivalent SQL's Latin1_General_CI_AS

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, collation, stringcomparer

I am implementing a caching layer between my database and my C# code. The idea is to cache the results of certain DB queries based on the parameters to the query. The database is using the default collation - either `SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS` or `Latin1_General_CI_AS`, which I believe based on some brief googling are equivalent for equality, just different for sorting.

I need a .NET StringComparer that can give me the same behavior, at least for equality testing and hashcode generation, as the database's collation is using. The goal is to be able to use the StringComparer in a .NET dictionary in C# code to determine whether a particular string key is already in the cache or not.

A really simplified example:

```
var comparer = StringComparer.??? // What goes here?

private static Dictionary<string, MyObject> cache =
    new Dictionary<string, MyObject>(comparer);

public static MyObject GetObject(string key) {
    if (cache.ContainsKey(key)) {
        return cache[key].Clone();
    } else {
        // invoke SQL "select * from mytable where mykey = @mykey"
        // with parameter @mykey set to key
        MyObject result = // object constructed from the sql result
        cache[key] = result;
        return result.Clone();
    }
}
public static void SaveObject(string key, MyObject obj) {
    // invoke SQL "update mytable set ... where mykey = @mykey" etc
    cache[key] = obj.Clone();
}
```

The reason it's important that the StringComparer matches the database's collation is that both false positives and false negatives would have bad effects for the code.

If the StringComparer says that two keys A and B are equal when the database believes they are distinct, then there could be two rows in the database with those two keys, but the cache will prevent the second one ever getting returned if asked for A and B in succession - because the get for B will incorrectly hit the cache and return the object that was retrieved for A.

The problem is more subtle if the StringComparer says that A and B are different when the database believes they are equal, but no less problematic. GetObject calls for both keys would be fine, and return objects corresponding to the same database row. But then calling SaveObject with key A would leave the cache incorrect; there would still be a cache entry for key B that has the old data. A subsequent GetObject(B) would give outdated information.

So for my code to work correctly I need the StringComparer to match the database behavior for equality testing and hashcode generation. My googling so far has yielded lots of information about the fact that SQL collations and .NET comparisons are not exactly equivalent, but no details on what the differences are, whether they are limited to only differences in sorting, or whether it is possible to find a StringComparer that is equivalent to a *specific* SQL collation if a general-purpose solution is not needed.

(Side note - the caching layer is general purpose, so I cannot make particular assumptions about what the nature of the key is and what collation would be appropriate. All the tables in my database share the same default server collation. I just need to match the collation as it exists)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Take a look at the [`CollationInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.metadata.collationinfo.aspx) class.  It is located in an assembly called  `Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.dll` although I am not totally sure where to get this.  There is a static list of [`Collations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.metadata.collationinfo.collations.aspx) (names) and a static method [`GetCollationInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee242913.aspx) (by name).

Each `CollationInfo` has a [`Comparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.metadata.collationinfo.comparer.aspx).  It is not exactly the same as a `StringComparer` but has similar functionality.

**EDIT:** Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.dll is a part of the Shared Management Objects (SMO) package.  This feature can be downloaded for SQL Server 2008 R2 here:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=16978#SMO

**EDIT:** `CollationInfo` does have a property named [`EqualityComparer`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.sqlparser.metadata.collationinfo.equalitycomparer.aspx) which is an `IEqualityComparer<string>`.

Comment: Unfortunately IComparer does not include the ability to get a hashcode - I need an IEqualityComparer which is what StringComparer provides.

Comment: @Stuart - See my edit, CollactionInfo does have an IEqualityComparer.

Comment: Is there a way to achieve the .NET SQL_Latin1_General_CP1_CI_AS equivalent by (simply) configuring or implementing a basic type?  SMO is a heavy-weight dependency for my situation.

Comment: Here is someone's unsuccessful attempt at using SMO: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11562042/achieving-consistent-sorting-between-c-sharp-and-sql-using-collationinfo-compare

Comment: There is an issue with this library. Sql doesn't consider trailing spaces when comparing strings but this library does.

Answer (score 14):

I've recently faced with the same problem: I need an `IEqualityComparer<string>` that behaves in SQL-like style. I've tried `CollationInfo` and its `EqualityComparer`. If your DB is always **_AS** (accent sensitive) then your solution will work, but in case if you change the collation that is **AI** or **WI** or whatever "insensitive" else the hashing will break.
Why? If you decompile **Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlParser.dll** and look inside you'll find out that `CollationInfo` internally uses `CultureAwareComparer.GetHashCode` (it's internal class of mscorlib.dll) and finally it does the following:

```
public override int GetHashCode(string obj)
{
  if (obj == null)
    throw new ArgumentNullException("obj");
  CompareOptions options = CompareOptions.None;
  if (this._ignoreCase)
    options |= CompareOptions.IgnoreCase;
  return this._compareInfo.GetHashCodeOfString(obj, options);
}
```

As you can see it can produce the same hashcode for "aa" and "AA", but not for "äå" and "aa" (which are the same, if you ignore diacritics (AI) in majority of cultures, so they should have the same hashcode). I don't know why the .NET API is limited by this, but you should understand where the problem can come from.
To get the same hashcode for strings with diacritics you can do the following: [create implementation](https://gist.github.com/yar-shukan/2c3bb818cdb168ef7c72#file-collationcomparer-cs) of `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementing the `GetHashCode` that will call appropriate `CompareInfo`'s object's `GetHashCodeOfString` via reflection because this method is internal and can't be used directly. But calling it directly with correct `CompareOptions` will produce the desired result:
See this example:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        const string outputPath = "output.txt";
        const string latin1GeneralCiAiKsWs = "Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_KS_WS";
        using (FileStream fileStream = File.Open(outputPath, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
        {
            using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(fileStream, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                string[] strings = { "aa", "AA", "äå", "ÄÅ" };
                CompareInfo compareInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(1033).CompareInfo;
                MethodInfo GetHashCodeOfString = compareInfo.GetType()
                    .GetMethod("GetHashCodeOfString",
                    BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic,
                    null,
                    new[] { typeof(string), typeof(CompareOptions), typeof(bool), typeof(long) },
                    null);

                Func<string, int> correctHackGetHashCode = s => (int)GetHashCodeOfString.Invoke(compareInfo,
                    new object[] { s, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreNonSpace, false, 0L });

                Func<string, int> incorrectCollationInfoGetHashCode =
                    s => CollationInfo.GetCollationInfo(latin1GeneralCiAiKsWs).EqualityComparer.GetHashCode(s);

                PrintHashCodes(latin1GeneralCiAiKsWs, incorrectCollationInfoGetHashCode, streamWriter, strings);
                PrintHashCodes("----", correctHackGetHashCode, streamWriter, strings);
            }
        }
        Process.Start(outputPath);
    }
    private static void PrintHashCodes(string collation, Func<string, int> getHashCode, TextWriter writer, params string[] strings)
    {
        writer.WriteLine(Environment.NewLine + "Used collation: {0}", collation + Environment.NewLine);
        foreach (string s in strings)
        {
            WriteStringHashcode(writer, s, getHashCode(s));
        }
    }
```

The output is:

```
Used collation: Latin1_General_100_CI_AI_KS_WS
aa, hashcode: 2053722942
AA, hashcode: 2053722942
äå, hashcode: -266555795
ÄÅ, hashcode: -266555795

Used collation: ----
aa, hashcode: 2053722942
AA, hashcode: 2053722942
äå, hashcode: 2053722942
ÄÅ, hashcode: 2053722942
```

I know it looks like the hack, but after inspecting decompiled .NET code I'm not sure if there any other option in case the generic functionality is needed.
So be sure that you'll not fall into trap using this not fully correct API.
**UPDATE:**
I've also created [the gist with potential implementation of "SQL-like comparer"](https://gist.github.com/yar-shukan/2c3bb818cdb168ef7c72#file-collationcomparer-cs) using `CollationInfo`.
Also there should be paid enough attention [where to search for "string pitfalls"](https://gist.github.com/yar-shukan/2c3bb818cdb168ef7c72#file-listofstringequalitypitfalls-cs) in your code base, so if the string comparison, hashcode, equality should be changed to "SQL collation-like" those places are 100% will be broken, so you'll have to find out and inspect all the places that can be broken. 
**UPDATE #2:**
There is better and cleaner way to make GetHashCode() treat CompareOptions. There is the class [SortKey](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.sortkey(v=vs.110).aspx) that works correctly with CompareOptions and it can be retrieved using

> CompareInfo.GetSortKey(yourString, yourCompareOptions).GetHashCode()

Here is the [link](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/globalization/compareinfo.cs,1dcf79e1e011a237) to .NET source code and implementation.

**UPDATE #3:**
If you're on .NET Framework 4.7.1+ you should use new `GlobalizationExtensions` [class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.globalizationextensions?view=netframework-4.8) as proposed by [this recent answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56694432/1725255).

Comment: +1 That is one seriously well researched answer! I wish I could vote you up more than once.

Comment: Please pay attention to UPDATE #2 - there is out of box way to make GetHashCode() work treating CompareOptions correctly. It's much cleaner way and doesn't require any reflection hacks. Unfortunately, I could find it only some time later after I made this post.

Comment: @yar_shukan If you can, please move your comment directly above this one to the very top of your answer as most people probably don't read the comments ;-). Thanks!

Comment: This really helped me out with a long-standing unique-key problem, especially with update 2. I now have a nice custom StringComparer I can use for my C# Dictionary :)

Answer (score 3):

The following is much simpler:

```
System.Globalization.CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(1033)
              .CompareInfo.GetStringComparer(CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreKanaType | CompareOptions.IgnoreWidth)
```

It comes from https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.globalization.globalizationextensions?view=netframework-4.8

It computes the hashcode correctly given the options given.
You'll still have to trim trailing spaces manually, as they as discarded by ANSI sql but not in .net

Here is a wrapper that trims spaces.

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;

namespace Wish.Core
{
    public class SqlStringComparer : IEqualityComparer<string>
    {
        public static IEqualityComparer<string> Instance { get; }

        private static IEqualityComparer<string> _internalComparer =
            CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo(1033)
                       .CompareInfo
                       .GetStringComparer(CompareOptions.IgnoreCase | CompareOptions.IgnoreKanaType | CompareOptions.IgnoreWidth);



        private SqlStringComparer()
        {
        }

        public bool Equals(string x, string y)
        {
            //ANSI sql doesn't consider trailing spaces but .Net does
            return _internalComparer.Equals(x?.TrimEnd(), y?.TrimEnd());
        }

        public int GetHashCode(string obj)
        {
            return _internalComparer.GetHashCode(obj?.TrimEnd());
        }

        static SqlStringComparer()
        {
            Instance = new SqlStringComparer();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice approach! This class was introduced starting from .NET Framework 4.7.1, but definitely worth of using instead of workarounds in my original post.

Answer (score 2):

SQL Server's [Server.GetStringComparer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sqlserver.management.smo.server.getstringcomparer%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) may be of some use.

Comment: Unfortunately IComparer does not include the ability to get a hashcode - I need an IEqualityComparer which is what StringComparer provides.