# Ordering with linq and integers with zeros at the end

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to order my list cards but push the zeros to the end.  I read a few responses on this here and tried the solution, but it doesn't seem to work.

Please see my linq query below.  (ToPackCards is just an extension to map to my custom object)

```
List<PackCard> packCards = db
  .PackCardEntities
  .OrderBy(pc => pc.PackNumber)
  .ThenBy(pc => pc.PickPosition == 0)
  .ThenBy(pc => pc.PickPosition)
  .ToList()
  .ToPackCards();
```

My data looks like this

Id|PackNumber|PickPosition|CardId

```
1|1|null|100 
2|1|null|120  
3|1|1|134  
4|1|2|232  
5|1|null|456
```

I want this to be sorted like this

```
3|1|1|134
4|1|2|232
1|1|null|100
2|1|null|120
5|1|null|456
```

What I get is this

```
1|1|null|100
2|1|null|120
5|1|null|456
3|1|1|134
4|1|2|232
```

Let me know if I am messing this up somehow, thanks!

Comment: If `PickPosition` is a nullable type, try  `pc.PickPosition != null`

Comment: duplicate? See this thread on custom comparer: http://stackoverflow.com/q/985657/353147

Comment: @Chuck Much more complicated scenario in the linked question, I knew that the solution shouldn't require a custom comparer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List<PackCard> packCards = db 
  .PackCardEntities 
  .OrderBy(pc => pc.PackNumber) 
  .ThenBy(pc => pc.PickPosition == null) 
  .ThenBy(pc => pc.PickPosition) 
  .ToList() 
  .ToPackCards();
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
List<PackCard> packCards = db.PackCardEntities
  .OrderBy(pc => pc.PackNumber)
  .ThenBy(pc => pc.PickPosition.HasValue? pc.PickPosition : int.MaxValue)
  .ToList().ToPackCards();
```