# Is it possible to make IEnumerable<char> implement IComparable?

Tags: c#, ienumerable, icomparable

As titled.

We all know if we want a class to be comparable and use in sorting i.e DataGrid, we will implement IComparable.

But for IEnumerable how can I do that?

I have a collection of a IEnumerable, we want to compare each IEnumerable to each other and do a sorting.

So say a collection `List<IEnumerable<char>>` that contains:

`IEnumerable<char> EnumableA` contains: "d", "e", "f"

`IEnumerable<char> EnumableB` contains: "d", "e", "c"

If we bind the collection `List<IEnumerable<char>>` to a DataGrid,
when we sort them in acs order, the order will be `EnumableB` 1st, then `EnumableA` the 2nd.

I do think of solution such as store the `EnumableA` into an object whichs implment `IComparable`, but then this would require to create another collection of objects, which will be expensive.

So is it possible or anyway to APPEND a `IComparable` interface and my sorting implmentation to the `IEnuerable<char>` so it will be sortable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out this post:
[Use own IComparer<T> with Linq OrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985657/use-own-icomparert-with-linq-orderby)

Use linq.orderby passing in your IComparable.

Comment: I don't really understand how can I apply that into databinding with DataGrid to do the sorting... I am not sorting it with Linq programmatically...

Comment: Oh wait, I missed your last sentense.  I think you are right. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Many of the places where `IComparable` can be used will also accept `IComparer`. It may be easier to write an `IComparer<IEnumerable<char>`.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do what you want to do would be to write a new class that implements both `IEnumerable<char>` and `IComparable`.

I'd probably implement `IList<char>`, and have a regular `List<char>` as the backing list, implementing all of IList with the same calls to the backing list, and implement IComparable however you need.

Of course, you could go the other way, and use the `string` class. It implements both `IComparable` and `IEnumerable<char>`, so that might be appropriate for what you want.

Comment: `string` implements `IEnumerable<char>` not `IEnumerable<string>`