# How can I sort but put zeros at the bottom?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

I have a list of objects that have a property Rank.  This is an integer.

I want to sort by rank on my view but when i do this:

```
  myObjects = myObjects.Orderby(r=>r.Rank);
```

i get all of the zeros (meaning these haven't been set at the top)

I want to order by 1 --> n but have the zeros be at the bottom of the list.

I would like it to be as efficient a sort as possible as the list is quite long

Answer (score 20, accepted):

LINQ:

```
myObjects = myObjects
    .OrderBy(r => r.Rank == 0) //false before true
    .ThenBy(r => r.Rank);
```

This *won't* actually do two full sorts. It will combine the two lambdas into a *single* dictionary sort across the two keys.

If you're not comfortable with the not-so-obvious `false`-before-`true` rule, you can replace the first lambda with `r => r.Rank == 0 ? 1 : 0` - but, knowing the `false`-before-`true` rule makes this seem really redundant.

Comment: is there any better way without having to do two full sorts?

Comment: @leora: See http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/04/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-26a-iorderedenumerable.aspx (and the subsequent posts) for some more details

Comment: @leora: This doesn't do two full sorts. "OrderBy/ThenBy" is pretty smart. Remember, the result of a query expression is *a query*, not *the computation of the results of the query*.  When the query is executed, the query knows whether there's a ThenBy after the OrderBy.

Comment: _"knowing the false-before-true rule"_ you could also use `OrderByDescending(r => r.Rank != 0)` instead.

Comment: @TimSchmelter How would that eliminate the need to *either* (A) "know the `false`-before-`true` rule" *or* (B) hide it by using something like a ternary operator (as in my example)? That lambda maps from `int` to `bool`, so it's still using the `false`-before-`true` rule.

Comment: @TimothyShields: It does not _eliminate_ the need to know it but it allows to keep your logic. So if you are interested in ranks that are different than zero first, you can use `OrderByDescending(r => r.Rank != 0)` instead of reversing your logic. Just a matter of taste.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Oooh - I'm sorry, I misread your comment. You were just offering an alternative that you thought was more intuitive. Gotcha. :)

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom comparer (implementing `IComparer`) and have it sort zeroes to the bottom. The pseudo code would be:

```
public class ZeroComparer : IComparer {
    public int Compare(Object intA, Object intB) {
        if(intA == 0 && intB != 0)
            return -1;
        if(intA != 0 && intB == 0)
            return 1;
        return int.Compare(intA, intB);
    }
}
```

Then use it like:

```
var comparer = new ZeroComparer();
myObjects = myObjects.Orderby(r=>r.Rank, comparer);
```

A quick example of how to use custom comparers:

[Use own IComparer<T> with Linq OrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985657/use-own-icomparert-with-linq-orderby)

Answer (score 1):

```
myObjects = myObjects.Orderby(r => r.Rank == 0 ? int.MaxValue : r.Rank);
```

to deal with the case `Rank == int.MaxValue` :

```
myObjects = myObjects.Orderby(r => r.Rank == 0 ? int.MaxValue : r.Rank - 1);
```

Comment: What if `int.MaxValue` is a valid value for `Rank`?

Comment: Good remark, so we need to take `1` to Rank in the order clause. Seed edited question.