# LINQ C# Group and Order

Tags: c#, linq, sorting, datatable

I've a little problem on a LINQ query to group and order my datatable. I'm on a winforms 3.5 project  with datagrid control (I know that isn't a very helpful control but i've no choice to change that :( ... unfortunately)

So, How can I make this custom order with LINQ ?

For example :

```
Name   | Age |
Test     38
Test-1   20
Test-2   18
Test2    40
Test2-1  24
Test2-2  16
```

Sort by age and keep hierarchy of name

exemple sort by descending

```
Name   | Age |
Test2    40
Test2-1  24
Test2-2  16
Test     38
Test-1   20
Test-2   18
```

I need to put the reslut of this query in a datatable to rebind my datagrid!

Comment: you should be able to create your own comparison function - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985657/use-own-icomparert-with-linq-orderby

Comment: What does the actual data look like in the database?  It's not clear from the example.

Comment: @tofutim This isn't linq to objects, its querying a database.

Comment: but you should still be able to do the ordering after the fact with linq

Comment: If at all possible you should refactor your database so that you have a "parent" column or something like that, rather than relying on string manipulation to try to figure out which rows are related.

Comment: Sorry I re-edit my post to make my request more understandable. It's not a LINQ to SQL but directly LINQ on datable bind with my datagrid to make a custom sort

Comment: Your data is not conducive to a good understanding of the required output.

Comment: In fact, my case is ... I have to "make survive" an old app ... 3.5 with a complexe framework based on a Datagrid and it's too long to rewrite with datagridview ... Now, I have to simulate a treeview in this datagrid and when I Click on a row I create an expand with "childs" ... So i would like to keep hierarchy after a sort ... Thats why I'm trying to find an issue with LINQ .. When I sort one column I have to keep the Hierarchy between parent and some "child rows"

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found a solution simply by ...

```
var query = myDataTable.AsEnumerable()
  .OrderByDesending( x => x.Field<type>("columnName"))
  .GroupBy( x => x.Field<type>'columnName").Substring(0,lenght)
  .SelectMany(x => x).CopyToDataTable();

  DataView.Table = query;
  DataView.Table.AcceptChange();
```

I'm not sure of my last SelectMany(x => x) but it's seems to work