# Order by field which is made of 3 sub strings in LINQ

Tags: c#, linq

I have a LINQ query as below,

```
 var sortedResults = (from r in this.CurrentTemplateInfos
                      where r.EffectiveEnd == null
                      orderby r.Description
                      select r);
```

From the above query ,field Description is made of 3 sub strings`(Showtype:Show:StartDate-Endate)` separated by Colon `(:)`. Now as per the new requirement `i` need to do orderby ascending for first two `fields(Showtype:Show)` and descending by `StartDate` from the description value, e.g.

```
Show : Main Street Trolley : 6/12/2010 - 7/15/2010

ShowType : Parades : 2/10/2010 - 6/16/2010

ShowType : Parades : 6/17/2010 - 8/26/2010

ShowType : Parades : 8/27/2010 - 10/26/2010
```

Output should be

```
Show : Main Street Trolley : 6/12/2010 - 7/15/2010

ShowType :Parades : 8/27/2010 - 10/26/2010

ShowType : Parades : 6/17/2010 - 8/26/2010

ShowType : Parades : 2/10/2010 - 6/16/2010
```

please help me on this.

Comment: What is `CurrentTemplateInfos`?

Comment: you need to implement Icomparer<T>. Here is an example http://stackoverflow.com/a/985685/1305119

Comment: Why do you store multiple informations in one property? Separate them from each other. Add other properties for  `StartDate`, `EndDate`(`DateTime`), `ShowType`, `Show`(`String`).

Answer (score 2):

Break the field up into separate fields with a helper type, and then use that in order by clauses. Something like:

```
// Elsewhere
class SortFields {
  public string Field1 { get; set; }
  public string Field2 { get; set; }
  public DateTime StartDate { get; set; }

  public static SortFields SplitInput(string input) {
    // Factory... Implement split/parse logic
  }
}
```

and then

```
from r in this.CurrentTemplateInfos
where r.EffectiveEnd == null
let fields = SortField.SplitInput(r.Description)
// This means sort by Field1, then Field2 and then StartDate
// and the default in each criterion is ascending unless you
// specify descending keyword.
orderby fields.Field1, fields.Field2, fields.StartDate descending 
select r
```

Note, one could use use multiple `let` clauses to do the split/parse, but I think the little helper type is clearer.

Comment: Good idea. But i think the best approach would be to store those informations in separate properties in the first place.

Comment: @TimSchmelter I agree. Equally implementing `IComparable<T>` on the type would be good.

Answer (score 1):

```
var sortedResults = from r in this.CurrentTemplateInfos
                    where r.EffectiveEnd == null
                    let parts = r.Description.Split(':')
                    let firstPart = parts[0] + parts[1]
                    let startDate = DateTime.Parse(parts[2].Split('-').First().Trim())
                    orderby firstPart, startDate descending
                    select r;
```

Comment: I was writing almost the same answer, but I would put the `where` right after `from`.

Comment: @Dennis_E I agree, changed.

Comment: @ Eren Ersönmez  : Thanks for your inputs. It really great and worked as expected. Thanks much.