# How can I sort a segmented string according to level using linq?

Tags: c#, linq, sorting

Is it possible to sort a list of segmented string according to their level and alphabetically using linq?

For example-

Given List

```
System
System.Collection.Generic
System.Generic
System.Linq
System.Linq.Collection.Generic
```

Sorted List

```
System
System.Generic
System.Linq
System.Collection.Generic
System.Linq.Collection.Generic
```

Comment: I think you could do this with a custom iComparable.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/985657/use-own-icomparert-with-linq-orderby

Comment: Have you even tried *anything* to achieve this? Or should we do your work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can order by the number of `.` in each string:

```
var sortedItems = items
    // Order by number of periods ("levels")
    .OrderBy(x => x.Count(c => c == '.'))

    // Then everything else alphabetically
    .ThenBy(x => x);
```

Here's a fiddle to demonstrate: https://dotnetfiddle.net/FivBPA

Comment: This is better than my answer as it doesn't rely on splitting the string

Comment: @TheLethalCoder I upvoted yours anyway, since you beat me to it. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you just need to order by number or parts and then a normal alphabetical order:

```
var result = list.OrderBy(s => s.Split('.').Length).ThenBy(s => s);
```

A better (and probably faster) way to do it would be to count the number of `.`s in the string instead of splitting on them (idea taken from [this answer by @NateBarbettini](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42700828/4631427)):

```
var result = list.OrderBy(s => s.Count(c => c == '.')).ThenBy(s => s);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can user  [`OrderBy()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534966(v=vs.110).aspx) with [`Count()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb535181(v=vs.110).aspx).

[Demo on .NetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/t2P7yG)

```
using System;
using System.Linq;


public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var k = @"System
System.Collection.Generic
System.Generic
System.Linq
System.Linq.Collection.Generic";

        // We split by new line, then order them by occurrence count of '.'
        var ordered = k.Split('\n').OrderBy(x => x.Count(l => l == '.'))

        foreach (var item in ordered)
            Console.WriteLine(item);
    }
}
```

output

```
System
System.Generic
System.Linq
System.Collection.Generic
System.Linq.Collection.Generic
```