# Linq OrderBy String Property Length Has To Be in Select List

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq

I am attempting to order the results of a Linq query by the length of a property and then by the property itself in order to order a string as an integer but the generated SQL is not ordering as I would expect it to.

I am joining multiple tables, filtering it down, selecting a DTO out with:

```
query = basequery.Select(s => new HeadersDTO
{
    headerid = s.Header.id,
    orderno = s.Header.orderno,
    customer = s.Header.customer,
    dateoforder = s.Header.dateoforder,
    consignee = s.Location.name,
    city = s.Location.name,
    state = s.Location.state
}).Distinct();
```

Then trying to order by  `s.Header.orderno`

```
 query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.orderno.Length).ThenByDescending(x => x.orderno)
.Skip(() => offset).Take(() => criteria.per_page);
```

This still orders it the normal way strings are ordered with first character taking precedence.

But if I select the `x.orderno.Length` out into it's own property and then order by that it works e.g.

```
query = basequery.Select(s => new HeadersDTO
{
    ordernolength = s.Header.orderno.Length <---- added this
    headerid = s.Header.id,
    orderno = s.Header.orderno,
    customer = s.Header.customer,
    dateoforder = s.Header.dateoforder,
    consignee = s.Location.name,
    city = s.Location.name,
    state = s.Location.state
}).Distinct();
```

```
 query = query.OrderByDescending(x => x.ordernolength).ThenByDescending(x => x.orderno)
.Skip(() => offset).Take(() => criteria.per_page);
```

Is there a way to do this where I don't have to create a new property in the select list?  I can add more information if needed.

Comment: `query.OrderByDescending(x => Int32.Parse(x.orderno))`

Comment: Is orderNo a numeric based string?

Comment: @SamAxe I've seen that before but it throws a `Linq To Entities does not recognize Int 32 Parse` error.

Comment: @DavidEspino it's always an integer in an nvarchar column (I did not design the schema).

Comment: Can you show us some sample data, how they are **currently** ordered and how you **want** them to be ordered? _Don't make up the data, use actual data you are experiencing now._

Comment: Have you examined the projected SQL between the two cases to see what's different?

Comment: @lamelemon materialize the query then apply the orderby.  That lets tge sort happen in linq to objects instead of EF.

Answer (score 0):

Try to create a custom Comparer using `IComparer` where you do the `Int32` check for this field. Here is an example for this:

[Use own IComparer<T> with Linq OrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985657/use-own-icomparert-with-linq-orderby)

Hope this helps

Comment: Or you could use the comparer to also compare with the `length` as the example does.

Comment: An `IComparer` won't help because the query is being used to project SQL. I don't know of an ORM that can project binary `IComparer` code functionality out to SQL, do you?