# Sort a list with where condition in linq c#

Tags: c#, list, linq

I have a `List` of type `Test` which has 4 `properties` and the `List` needs to be sorted with some specific conditions. Below are the `properties` of `class` `Test` and also sample data.

```
class Test
{
    int order;
    string value;
    string dept;
    //..... and some others
}
```

**Sample json:**

```
[
   {
      "order":3,
      "value":"ABC",
      "dept":"A"
   },
   {
      "order":2,
      "value":"XYZ",
      "dept":"A"
   },
   {
      "order":1,
      "value":"ABC2",
      "dept":"P"
   },
   {
      "order":4,
      "value":"XYZ2",
      "dept":"P"
   },
   {
      "order":6,
      "value":"ABC3",
      "dept":"Z"
   },
   {
      "order":5,
      "value":"XYZ3",
      "dept":"Z"
   },
]
```

The above `json` data is loaded to one `List<Test>`.

My requirement is to sort the above list like first the items with `dept=P`, then `dept=A` and then `dept=Z` and the second sort criteria is `order`.

I tried with `OrderBy(x=>x.dept).ThenBy(x=>x.order)` but the output is not what is expected.

Is there any way to specify the `dept` which should appear first in the list.

As a workaround I split the `List` into multiple lists and then `merge` them after `sorting`, but this is not the best solution I guess.

Do we have any other better and optimized solution for this?

Comment: There's an override of `Enumerable.OrderBy` that takes an `IComparer<TKey> comparer` as its second parameter. You could write your own `DeptComparer : IComparer<String>` that would handle your desired `P>A>Z` order. See [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985657/use-own-icomparert-with-linq-orderby) and [the docs on OrderBy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.orderby?view=netframework-4.8) for more information.

Comment: Ohh! Thank you so much @pappbence96 for pointing this out I will just look into it now.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, you could create a list with your sorting rules:

```
var orderOfDepts = new List<string> { "P", "A", "Z" };
```

And use index of elements in that list for sorting:

```
var sortedList = myList.OrderBy(x=> orderOfDepts.IndexOf(x.dept)).ThenBy(x=> x.order).ToList();
```

P.S.
This solution is good if `sortedList` collection is not too big, but if it is large or you have many sorting rules in `orderOfDepts`  list then you might want to reduce the overall complexity of this algorithm from > `O(N2)`  to something close to `O(N*logN)`.

For that we can utilize `Dictionary`s fast lookups:

```
int o;
var orderOfDepts = new Dictionary<string, int> 
{
   { "P", 0 },
   { "A", 1 },
   { "Z", 2 }
};

var sortedList = myList.OrderBy(x => orderOfDepts.TryGetValue(x.dept, out o) ? o : int.MaxValue)
                       .ThenBy(x=> x.order)
                       .ToList();
```

Here we try to get element from the dictionary by key `x.dept`. If we don't find anything we put the item to the end of the list otherwise we use the value from the dictionary for sorting.

Dictionary's lookup is O(1) so it will greatly improve performance in the expense of the time that is required in order to construct the dictionary object. For few elements it would be inadvisable to do it and first solution is better but for large amounts of data this solution is good.

Comment: This is more concise than my suggestion about `IComparer`s and works great.

Comment: Thank you @Fabjan. My list can have 40 items max will it be a performance issue?

Comment: @TufanChand No it should be all right, I'd tend to use second solution with > 1000 records

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var orderOfDepts = new List<string> { "P", "A", "Z" };

var sortedList =
(
    from x in myList
    join dept in orderOfDepts.Select((name, index) => new { name, index }) on x.dept equals dept.name
    orderby dept.index, x.order
    select x
).ToList();
```

It should be fairly efficient.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it this way

```
var result = _context.OrderBy(p => new { p.dept, p.order}).ToList();
```