# Dynamic linq orderBy by non existent field

Tags: c#, linq

I have an ObservableCollection, which consists of objects from a base type and derived type both.

```
public class BaseClass    
{
      public string First{get;set}
      public ObservableCollection<BaseClass> Items {get;set}
}
public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
      public Second{get;set}
}
```

the usage is with:

```
ObservableCollection<BaseClass> MyList;
MyList.Add(new BaseClass());
MyList.Add(new DerivedClass());
```

The requirement is to sort this collection on different properties,
so to avoid "switch case" I have used dyanmic orderBy, as in:

```
MyList = new ObservableCollection<BaseClass>(MyList.AsQueryable().OrderBy(field));
```

MyList is actually a tree, and the sort is called recursively for ~1,000,000 items total, so performance is crucial here.
I understood the dynamic orderBy is faster that reflection - getting property value for field name and comparing it. (or am I wrong?!?)

Now the problem is some properties exist in the derived type, but not in base, so sort is not performed correctly.
How can I implement some comparer to handle missing fields as null/empty?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Use own IComparer<T> with Linq OrderBy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/985657/use-own-icomparert-with-linq-orderby)

Comment: @BurnsBA it uses property.GetValue(x), which I thought was heavier for performance.
my collection is actually a tree, and sort is called recursively. total items can be more than a million objects.

Comment: I don't think this error should happen unless MyList is defined as `ObservableCollection<BaseClass>` rather than `ObservableCollection<DerivedClass>`.

Comment: You should post benchmarks, and your implementation showing how "sort is not performed correctly"

Comment: C# is a language of types. What is `T` in your sample sort code? What type is `field`?

Answer (score 0):

You could implement IComparer and inspect the types but it may not be any cleaner than another solution:

```
public class CustomComparer : IComparer<BaseClass>
{
    public int Compare(BaseClass a, BaseClass b)
    {
        //whatever custom logic you want to use for sorting can be added here 
        if (a is DerivedClass ac && b is DerivedClass bc) 
           return Compare(ac.DerivedId, bc.DerivedId);

        //.. would have to handle a being Derived when b is not, and opposite.

        return Compare(a.Id, b.Id);
    }

    private int Compare(int a, int b)
    {
        if (a > b)
            return 0;

        if (a < b)
            return -1;

        return 1;
    }

}

public class BaseClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
}

public class DerivedClass : BaseClass
{
    public int DerivedId { get; set; } // not on base
}
```

You could simply call:

```
CustomComparer comp = new CustomComparer();
list.Sort(comp); // Sort is extension on List, not ObservableCollection
```

Comment: thanks @Anthony G., but I need dynamic sort - I am getting the field name as string.